# RDL 2016 Report Builder skip a line for an optional parameter

Tags: templates, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, rdl

I have an RDL template which contains of several parameters. They are all optional and marked:

- Allow Null Value
- Allow Blank Value ("")

It is important that they are optional since sometimes the address does not contain AddressLine3 (or in fact AddressLine1 or AddressLine2, or even PostCode):

[image]

They are all dropped together in one textbox area, and it all works well, but the problem is if I don't pass one of the optional params (AddressLIne2 in the example below) - an empty line is preserved in the report:

[image]

Any ideas on how to make that empty line disappear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to replace the list of 5 parameters with a single expression. Something like this.

```
=
Parameters!FullName.Value & IIF(IsNothing(Parameters!FullName.Value), Nothing, vbcrlf) &
Parameters!AddressLine1.Value & IIF(IsNothing(Parameters!AddressLine1.Value), Nothing, vbcrlf) &
Parameters!AddressLine2.Value & IIF(IsNothing(Parameters!AddressLine2.Value), Nothing, vbcrlf) &
Parameters!AddressLine3.Value & IIF(IsNothing(Parameters!AddressLine3.Value), Nothing, vbcrlf) &
Parameters!PostCode.Value
```

This simply concatenates each parameter value with a new line added only if the parameter was not empty.

---

**Demo data**

The following shows the same principle applied to some address data from the sample AdventureWorks database

The report shows all address fields for illustration

[image]

Which gives the following output
[image]